# Вызов функций java из нативного кода

Tags: java, android, c++, native

Необходимо переписать `java` код на `c++` в `Android Strudio`.Интересуют вопросы:

1. Как из `c++` вызвать функции `java` например `new Random`
2. Как из `c++` вызвать и работать с библиотеками `ava` например `picasso`
3. Как в `c++` определить интерфейсы(обратный вызов,слушатели), а в `java` их использовать

Comment: У вас очень общий вопрос. Да и если быть точным, это три вопроса. Опишите подробно, что именно вы пытались сделать и что конкретно не получилось.

Comment: Ключевое слово `JNI (Java Native Interface)` - ищите учебные материалы, изучайте. Эта технология позволяет вызывать нативный код из java и наоборот.

Comment: @ woesss знаю, но не нашел как решить вопросы из вопроса

Comment: @Ivan [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) искали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример создания объекта Random в нативном коде и вызова его метода

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/util/Random");

jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");
if (NULL == ctor) return NULL;
jobject rndObj = env->NewObject(cls, ctor);

jmethodID nextInt = env->GetMethodID(cls, "nextInt", "()I");
if (NULL == nextInt) return NULL;
jint rndNumber = env->CallObjectMethod(rndObj, nextInt);
```

Работа с классами из сторонних библиотек осуществляется аналогично. А интерфейсы, очевидно, в нативном коде не определяются.

Comment: ()V - void и т.д.Как тогда быть с интерфейсами?Обфусцировать это все дело не получится верно?

Comment: Что "()V - void и т.д."?

Comment: Надо объяснить подробнее, чего именно вам нужно от "интерфейсов". Всегда есть другие способы решить задачу.

Comment: Разные случаи.Например как загружены данные возвратить результат.Ругается на jint rndNumber = env->CallObjectMethod(rndObj, nextInt); - Taking integer from pointer 'jobject' without a cast

Comment: Вообще стоит защищаться от взлома натив методами или это пустая трата времени?

Comment: Для разных случаев разные ответы. Ну сделайте приведение. Если  вы ждёте, что я в режиме реального времени буду писать с вами программу, то это зря.

Comment: Использование JNI существенно утяжелит разработку и сопровождение программы. Это окупится только в том случае, если у вас уникальный алгоритм, который приносит вам много денег и который все хотят украсть.

Comment: взламываю и выкладывают уже

Comment: @Ivan это не та галочка. жмите на серую, слева от рейтинга ответа.